# Angular 5 problemas com rotas

Tags: angular, rotas, angular-routes

Galera eu tenho minha rota normal  e simples 
app.routing.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { LoginComponent } from '../login/login.component';
import { HomeComponent } from '../home/home.component';
import { CursosComponent } from '../cursos/cursos.component';
import { CursoDetalheComponent } from '../cursos/curso-detalhe/curso-detalhe.component';
import { PageNotFoundComponent } from '../page-not-found/page-not-found.component';

const PORTAL_ROUTER: Routes = [
// { path: '', redirectTo: '/dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
{ path: '', component: HomeComponent },
{ path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
{ path: 'cursos', component: CursosComponent },
{ path: 'curso/:id', component: CursoDetalheComponent },
{ path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(PORTAL_ROUTER)],
  exports: [ RouterModule ]
})

export class PortalRoutingModule {}
```

as rotas básicas funciona
localhost/login ou localhost/cursos, porém, quando eu visualizo a rota com parâmetro, no caso o id, ela me mostra da seguinte maneira
localhost/cursos/curso/1
e claro que assim vai dar erro, pois teria que mostrar localhost/curso/1, esta é maneira correta

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa passar o caminho absoluto para a rota.

Exemplo redirecionando por código:

```
this.router.navigate(['/curso/1'])
```

Exemplo redirecionando por links:

```
 <a [routerLink]="/curso/1">Link</a>
```